# Nextjs with next-i18next: How to generate a sitemap for every domain?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing, nextjs-rewrites

I am building a Next.js project that supports [multiple domains](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#domain-routing) through the next-i18next package (without using Sub-path Routing). Now, I need to create different sitemaps for the various domains that I support. I plan to statically generate these sitemaps and have them accessible as pages within their respective domains. Generating the sitemaps for the different domains won't be an issue. I can create a script and run this with:

`"export": "next build && node ./src/scripts/generate-sitemap",`

However, I'm uncertain about where to place these files and how to make them available across the different domains my site is running on. I would like to have them accessible on just `example.com/sitemap.xml`, `example.de/sitemap.xml`, etc. The sites will rely heavily on SEO, so it is crucial for me to get this right and do it the best way possible (SEO-wise).

For instance, when building the project, I see a folder `.next` is created. This folder contains a /server/pages directory. In there I can see the different locales I currently support. Wouldn't it be best to push the sitemap.xml files to these folders respectively?

Answer (score 0):

So the best way i found was to use rewrites with api routes.

This way you can control exactly which pages get shown in the sitemap ect.

I also used this for my robots.txt

```
async rewrites() {
return [
    {
        source: '/robots.txt',
        destination: '/api/robots'
    },
    {
      source: '/sitemap.xml',
      destination: '/api/sitemap'
    }
];
```

}

Comment: Yeah, this is a possible way, but this means that the sitemap.xml files are not statically generated right? They will be generated once a request to /api/sitemap is made, correct? I don't think SEO-wise this may be the best way. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Reinier68 For my use case it was best not to have it static. When content is updated the sitemap can auto update this way. Personally i have found 0 seo issues using this way and our sites score 100 on the sitemap checker - https://seositecheckup.com/. Google and other search engines dont have issues with this format.

Comment: @Matt facing a similar issue, can you please provide your `/api/sitemap` and `/api/robots` files? My issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77811667/sitemaps-for-multilingual-multidomain-next-js-site