# Sitemaps for multilingual, multidomain Next.JS site

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Looks like I need `sitemap-en.xml` and `sitemap-de.xml` in the root.
From all the solutions, I like the idea of using rewrites and generating sitemaps with `/api`

```
//next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
...
async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
            source: '/sitemap.xml',
            destination: '/api/sitemap',
        },
    ]
},
...
}
```

And

```
// /api/sitemap.ts
export async function GET() {
  const xmlContent = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    ...
  </urlset>`;

  return new Response(xmlContent, { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/xml" } });
}
```

It returns errors and can't be built even without logic to grab pages. How do I go with this?

I'm using Next.JS 13.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create route:

for App Router:
root/sitemap-en.xml/route.ts
root/sitemap-de.xml/route.ts

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm, and it seems like I need to specify both of them in a single robots.txt, right?

Comment: i used this in my robots.txt.

# Sitemaps
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: https://example.com/server-sitemap.xml